# Can't able to edit my input when the stayDays is greater than 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, logic

In this input I can't able to edit below the mainRate when the staydays is greater than 1. Ex. if my mainRate is 990 and the Total ADvance came as 2990 and when I edit this total advance I can't able to edit it less than 990(mainRate). I guess their might be problem with my logic .

```
<p>Total Advance</p>
  <input
                      style={{ width: '4rem' }}
                      type="text"
                      value={
                        Number(staydays) > 1
                          ? roomno.length * mainAvanceRate +
                          roomno.length *
                          Number(mainRate) *
                          Number(staydays - 1)
                          : roomno.length * mainAvanceRate
                      }

                      name="mainAvanceRate"
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        setmainAvanceRate(
                          e.target.value / Number(roomno.length),
                        )

                      }
                    />
```

I want to edit the input box. When the stay days is 1 then it gets edited but when the input is greater than 1 it doesn't get below the mainRate .